Управление порядком вычисления выражений с плавающими точкой (ассоциативность)
Встретился, тут такой параноидальный код (scipy.special (cephes)):
/* Computes fl(a+b) and err(a+b).  */
XSF_HOST_DEVICE inline double two_sum(double a, double b, double *err) {
    volatile double s = a + b;
    volatile double c = s - a;
    volatile double d = b - c;
    volatile double e = s - c;
    *err = (a - e) + d;
    return s;
}

Т.е. гарантировано корректно работает с любыми ключами компиляции, но столь же гарантировано медленно, ибо стандарты C/C++ требуют записи/чтения памяти.
Что собственно немного противоречит его изначальному предназначению: быстрая реализация четверной точности. Нет, конечно, программную реализацию IEEE bynary128 (_Float128 и float128_t) он и в таком виде обгоняет, но...
В библиотеке qd откуда предыдущий код был родом, он выглядел так:
/* Computes fl(a+b) and err(a+b).  */
inline double two_sum(double a, double b, double &err) {
  double s = a + b;
  double bb = s - a;
  err = (a - (s - bb)) + (b - bb);
  return s;
}

Тут понятно, шустро, но при применении широко известного ключа -ffast-math или менее известного -fassociative-math тут же возвращаемый результат err становится тождественным 0.. На этот счёт Дэвид Бейли написал в документации: "не применяйте такие ключи".
Что немного обидно, пишешь рядом static_assert() и assert():
static inline constexpr
bool check_two_sum(double a, double b,
                   double _s, double _err) {
    double err = 0.;
    double s = two_sum(a, b, err);
    return s == _s && err == _err;
}
...
    static_assert(check_two_sum(1e-35, 1., 1., 1e-35));
    assert(check_two_sum(1e-35, 1., 1., 1e-35));

static_assert() всегда проходит, а assert() срабатывает (хотя иногда нестабильно, вроде как не на всех компиляторах).
Немного более обидно, что если gcc выставляет два макроса: __FAST_MATH__ и/или __ASSOCIATIVE_MATH__, то clang выставляет только один __FAST_MATH__, что не позволяет детектировать проблему вызванную ключом -fassociative-math.
Что ещё более обидно:

У clang соответствующая _Pragma(), исключающая только этот вид оптимизации, действует на охватывающий блок, т.е. её надо вставлять внутрь функции, и это единственный вариант;
У gcc есть два варианта: классический push_options/pop_options, и вариант с атрибутом функции, т.е. её надо вставлять перед описанием функции;
У MSVC есть только классический вариант push/pop.

У icc (Intel), вроде как у gcc и т.п. В общем, из-за clang нет единой схемы.
Пока непонятно, как для разных компиляторов, но хотя бы в едином стиле детектировать и/или обходить проблему?
И основной вопрос. Правильно ли я понимаю, что, по крайней мере, в современных спецификациях C23/C++23 (C23, 6.5 Expressions, абзац 8, FP_CONTRACT) разрешается, в том или ином виде сокращение плавающих операций в рамках одного выражения, но не между операторами? Т.е. корректный по C23/C++23 код (в данном случае, корректность строго определена: a + b == s + err && s == s ⨁ err, где + - точная математическая сумма, а ⨁ - машинная сумма, Деккер, или Кнут, т.2, теорема 4.2.2A), должен быть таким:
/* Computes fl(a+b) and err(a+b).  */
inline double two_sum(double a, double b, double *err) {
    auto s = a + b;
    auto c = s - a;
    auto d = b - c;
    auto e = s - c;
    *err = (a - e) + d;
    return s;
}

Т.е. сейчас в C/C++ не как в Fortran, на скобки надежды нет?

Весь код до ; выполняется до всего кода после неё. Sequence point. В последнем варианте вы зафиксировали порядок вычисления пяти кусочков кода. Задача решена. И это очень старый механизм так было в  C самого его рождения.

@StanislavVolodarskiy , во-первых, это неудобно, и, во-вторых, вроде как, до какого-то момента (сейчас точно не помню, до какого), было достаточно скобок. В-третьих, формально, Sequence point недостаточно, ввиду того, что никто не видит же, прямо по стандартам - нет видимых побочных эффектов. В память записывать не обязательно, компиляторы и не записывают.

FP_CONTRACT — это не про сокращение выражения (a - (s - bb)) + (b - bb) до a - s + b. Речь идёт о том, что всё выражение (a - (s - bb)) + (b - bb) (или его часть) может быть вычислено как единая операция без промежуточных ошибок округления. n3301 / 6.5.1 / 9: A floating expression may be contracted, that is, evaluated as though it were a single operation, thereby omitting rounding errors implied by the source code and the expression evaluation method.85) The intermediate operations in the contracted expression are evaluated as if to infinite range and precision ....

Что разрешает компилятору, например, использовать для выражения x + y * z fused multiply–add инструкцию.

@Serge3leo, изменение результата при переупорядочении операций - видимый побочный эффект. И он запрещён точкой-с-запятой. Неудобство я даже не поминаю. Вам нужен результат? Забудьте про неудобства.

корректный по C23/C++23 код должен быть таким: ... Нужны более чёткие критерии корректности. Если в разных реализациях используется тип double разной битности (64- и 128-битный, например), и соответственно приведённая функция в этих реализациях выдаёт отличающиеся результаты на одних и тех же входных данных (в качестве входных данных мы подобрали вещественные числа, представимые точно в обоих разновидностях double'ов), то такое поведение считается корректным?

@wololo, ну да, они это написали затем, что бы a*b + c можно было превратить в fma(a, b, c). Но, вроде как, они разрешили и (a*b) + c тоже преобразовывать, в частности, вроде как, иногда нет возможности корректно написать (a*b) + c*d (и мне известны случаи, когда это вызывает проблемы). Тоже может касаться и скобок с чистым сложением, гипотетически, если у нас есть операция add3() или add4()`, то этот пункт разрешает их использовать невзирая на скобки, и тут тоже могу быть грабли.

@wololo , в данном случае, корректность строго определена: a + b == s + err && s == s ⨁ err, где + - точная сумма, а ⨁ - машинная сумма, Кнут, т.2, теорема 4.2.2A.

@StanislavVolodarskiy , как бы, мне нужен максимально удобный и эффективный результат. К примеру, вариант volatile - даёт гарантированную точность, но тормозной. С точки зрения, известных компиляторов, вроде как, нет смысла писать разные операторы, т.к. полезные ключи -fassociative-math (clang/gcc/icc) или /fp:fast (MSVC), кладут на них с прибором. Тут больше вопрос с удобным детектированием/запретом, ну и пониманием того, что именно детектировать/запрещать. А вот в деле FP_CONTRACT не понятно, @wololo пишет, что я его расширенно трактую.

"Полезные ключи" приводят к багам. Если они реально вам нужны, соберите математику в отдельный файл и там её разгоняйте. А весь остальной проект собирайте без этих ускорителей. Если так не получится, то я могу вам только посочувствовать. Вам придётся разбирать каждое выражение по отдельности. Универсального рецепта нет.

А вообще, если нужно гарантировать решение, то пишите такие куски кода в отдельном файле на ассемблере
